# Matlab; Partial Differential Equation; ODE

Tags: matlab, math, ode, pde

I am currently trying to solve a Matlab problem. For the first part, I need to hand solve Partial Differential Equation with initial and boundary condition. However, I am lost because I don't know how to continue solving the problem after I find the equation for finding T. There is an ODE inside the boundary condition, and with that ODE, there are another initial condition. How can I link everything together? I have also attached with my work as well. Please give me some idea, thank you.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PuQh.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6J0N.png)

Comment: You will discretize both the body and the boundary condition as transient equation.  Solve both incrementally using the same time step.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I am still kind of confuse. How can I do that? I know how to find the equation in order to find T, but how I can solve the other solve that ODE, since in the ODE, there is q(t)=dT/dt (x=0,t). This part is very confusing for me. Would you mind give me some example?

Comment: That's not an ODE.  It's a boundary condition that specifies the temperature gradient at the boundary for all time (cf. [Neumann boundary condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_boundary_condition)).

Comment: so how can i link those together?